Showing the law of $(X,Y)$ for normally distributed $X$ and $Y$ is invariant to rotations
Let $X,Y \sim \mathsf{N}(0,1)$ be two independent real random varialbles. Show that their law is invariant to rotations.
Be a corollary from class, $X,Y$ are independent $\iff$ $\forall x,y\in \Bbb{R}$, $P(X\le x, Y\le y)=P(X\le x)P(Y\le y)$.
The problem is that the above equality consists of CDFs and not PDFs.
I am having an issue seeing the distinction between CDF and PDF. While the law was defined as $L_x:=P\circ X^{-1}$, the CDF is the defined as $P(X\le x)=L_x((-\infty,x])$. So if $P(X\le x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} f(t)dt$, then how is $f(x)=\frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ expressed through the probability function $P$? A distinction between the two in the context of this question would be valuable as I it gets mixed up for me in this question.
I know that the expression $f(x)f(y)$ with the PDF of $X$ being $f(x)=\frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt {2\pi}}$ is invariant to rotations, but I can't seem to understand what the above stand for in term of probabilities. I could use some help figuring out where I got confused.
Thank you in advance!

$P(X=y)P(Y=y)=\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-r^2}$ is surely wrong. $P(X=y)=P(Y=y)=0$.

@geetha290krm Edited: that was a type, sorry, corrected.

@Meitar No you acutally didn't… it still hold $P(X=x)P(Y=y) = 0\cdot 0 = 0$ which is far away from "Clearly […]".
For continuous random variables $Z$ you always have $P(Z=z) = 0$ and since you are dealing with normals here, this holds as well for $X$ and $Y$.

Let me revisit the definitions and see where the error occurred, Thanks!

@Gono You're both correct. I further edited my question to reflect the core of my misunderstanding.

The expression "law is invariant to rotations" means that for any rotation $\ \Theta\ ,$ and any measurable set $\ A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2\ ,$
$$
P\big((X,Y)\in\Theta A\big)=P\big((X,Y)\in A\big)\ .
$$
Now,
$$
P\big((X,Y)\in\Theta A\big)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\iint_{\Theta A}e^\frac{-\|(x,y)\|^2}{2}d\ell_2^{\,\color{red}{\dagger}}\ ,
$$
and by changing variables in the above integral from $\ (x,y)\ $ to $\ (u,v)\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}$$\,\Theta^{-1}\big((x,y)\big)\ ,$ and applying the standard result for the form of the resulting integral, we have
\begin{align}
P\big((X,Y)\in\Theta A\big)&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\iint_{\Theta A}e^\frac{-\|(x,y)\|^2}{2}d\ell_2\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\iint_Ae^\frac{-\|\Theta((u,v))\|^2}{2}|\det\Theta|d\ell_2\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\iint_Ae^\frac{-\|(u,v)\|^2}{2}d\ell_2\\
&=P\big((X,Y)\in A\big)\ ,
\end{align}
because rotations are isometric and have determinant $1$.
$^\color{red}{\dagger}$ Where $\ \ell_2\ $ is Lebesgue measure on $\ \mathbb{R}^2\ .$

thanks! Could you explain how $(X,Y)$ is both in $A$ and $A$'s rotation $\Theta A$? Maybe $\Theta (X,Y) \in \Theta A$?

Remember that $\ (X,Y)\ $ is a random vector.  It's in $\ A\ $ with probability $\ P((X,Y)\in A)\ $ and in the rotation $\ \Theta A\ $ of $\ A\ $ with probability $\ P((X,Y)\in \Theta A)\ .$ While these two probabilities are equal, this doesn't mean that $\ (X,Y)\ $ is simultaneously in both $\ A\ $ and $\ \Theta A\ .$ The probability of this last event is $\ P((X,Y)\in A\cap\Theta A)\ ,$ which will be zero if $\ A\cap\Theta A=\varnothing\ ,$ for instance.

Lastly, I have a problem with the first step. Can I say that $A=\pi_1(A)\times \pi_2 (A)$ to say that $P((X,Y)\in A)=P(X\in \pi_1(A),Y\in \pi_2(A))=\int\int_{\pi_1(A)\times\pi_2(A)}=\int\int_{A}$ or am I completely guessing here? Not mentioned whether Borel is involved, but I think it is.

(the L-RHS being after using Fubini's theorem)

No, in general $\ A\ $ doesn't necessarily have to be a cartesian product, and the double integrals are, strictly speaking, integrals with respect to Lebesgue measure on $\ \mathbb{R}^2\ .$  I have now modified my answer to clarify this point.

Hint: The key to prove this statement is to understand a "rotation" of the random vector $\begin{bmatrix} X \\ Y \end{bmatrix}$ means left-multiplying a special orthogonal matrix $R = \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ -\sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$ with $\begin{bmatrix} X \\ Y \end{bmatrix}$.
Now use the well-known property of the Gaussian vector: if $\mathbf{X} \sim N(\mathbf{\mu}, \Sigma)$, then $A\mathbf{X} \sim N(A\mu, A\Sigma A^\top)$.

Thanks! I am not sure I know how $(X,Y)$ distributes. Is $\mu,\Sigma$ a pair of measure and $\sigma$-algebra or a pair of a mean(expectation) and a variance ($\sigma$)$?

@Meitar $X, Y \text{ i.i.d.} \sim N(0, 1)$ means $\begin{bmatrix} X \ Y \end{bmatrix} \sim N\left(\begin{bmatrix} 0 \ 0 \end{bmatrix}, I_{(2)}\right)$.

I think my misunderstanding is due to conflating "Law" and "Pdf", which are different. I think I am getting it now!

@Meitar For normal distribution, they are still the same (in the sense of describing the random variable -- as functions, they are surely different).  In general, "Law" is a synonym for "distribution";  if the distribution also admits a pdf (i.e., density), then these three concepts coincide.
